# React edit form values disappear on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Imagine a page with a blog post. At the bottom of the post there is a button 'Edit post' which links to a page /posts/:postId/edit. You click the button and you can see the blog post details inside the form. All good here. However, if you refresh the page the input fields become empty.

This is edit button within the blog post:

```
<button onClick={event => 
this.props.history.push(`/posts/edit/${post.id}`)}>Edit post</button>
```

The post details are fetched using the :postId from the URL which suggests that there should not be any difference whether the page is accessed from a button or the URL is typed manually.

This is how I get the post details:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.fetchPost(this.props.match.params.postId)
}
```

And this is how I populate the form:

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="35" defaultValue={post.title} />
```

Another interesting thing. If I just display `{post.title}` in a `<p>` element somewhere on the page, it still appears after a page refresh.

Now, why would the edit form become empty after a page refresh (or manually typed URL) if the post details are always requested using the :postId in the URL?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTH0x.png)

P.S. I am using Redux

Comment: replace `defaultValue` with `value` might solve the issue

Comment: I suppose you get the request response after the first render in which you are rendering inputs with `undefined` `defaultValue`, you may want to wait for these values before rendering the inputs or use controlled input by setting their values in the component state.

Comment: Changing defaultValue to value fixes the problem visually but throws an error "input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled elements (or vice-versa)". I tried it yesterday but could not overcome the error with local state and onChange handlers. Maybe I just didn't implement it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Added a state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleContentChange = this.handleContentChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      body: '',
      title: ''
    }
  }
```

Fetch the post same as before:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPost(this.props.match.params.postId)
  }
```

Added componentWillReceiveProps function:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(data) {
    this.setState({ title: data.post.title });
    this.setState({ body: data.post.body });
  }
```

Added onChange handlers for the input fields:

```
  handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ title: event.target.value });
  }

  handleContentChange(event) {
    this.setState({ body: event.target.value });
  }
```

And finally the input fields:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitPost}>
 <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
 <input type="text" id="title" onChange={this.handleTitleChange} name="title" size="35" value={this.state.title} />
 <label htmlFor="content">Content</label>
 <p>{ post.body }</p>
 <textarea type="text" id="body" name="body" onChange={this.handleContentChange} rows="4" cols="60" value={this.state.body} />
 <button type="submit">Update post</button>
</form>
```

Seems to be working properly for now.